# Failed to parse access token response: Error: Error while making request: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN accounts.google.com:443. Error code: EAI_AGAIN\

Tags: ios, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already used

```
"firebase-admin": "^6.3.0",
```

I did on NodeJS

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://myapp.firebaseio.com"
});
```

I kept getting this in the logs

> @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Failed to parse access token response: Error: Error while making request: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN accounts.google.com:443. Error code: EAI_AGAIN\"."}

This used to work like 2 weeks ago. I don't know what changed.

How would one go about and debug this further?

Comment: This may not be on your side. Looks like a DNS error..